# AmazonWebService - Should i use AWS API Gateway or AWS SDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to call a lambda function from NodeJS. After research i know 2 ways to do it:

1. Assign Lambda function into AWS API Gateway and call that API.
2. Call Lambda function through AWS SDK

What are pros and cons of API Gateway and AWS SDK ? And when to use each way above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. API Gateway is mostly used to give temporary access to Lambda functions in environments that are not secure (i.e. browsers, desktop apps, NOT servers).

If your environment is secure, as in it runs on an EC2 instance with an IAM role, or another server with secure stored credentials, then feel free to use the SDK and call the Lambda function correctly.

If you need to expose your Lambda function to the entire internet, or to authorised users on the web, or to any user that has the potential to grab the access key and secret during transit, then you will want to stick API Gateway in front.

With API Gateway you can secure your Lambda functions with API keys, or through other authorisers such as Amazon Cognito so that users need to sign in before they can use the API endpoint. This way they only gain temporary credentials, rather than permanent ones that shouldn't be available to anyone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can i ask one more thing : which way is easier to use ? ( about coding maybe ).

Comment: Pretty much the same tbh. It's not really about what is easier though, it is about what is correct. API Gateway in front of Lambda just because you're more comfortable writing http requests is not the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks, i understand it all.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with _DF about the security concern on invoking lambda directly through client. Over the 4 years I implementing Client + AWS SDK on my serverless approach. Direct hit to all microservices we have such as Lambda, DynamoDB, S3, SQS, etc.

To work with this approach, we have to strong understand about IAM Role Policy including its statements concept, Authentication Token, AWS Credential, and Token - Credential exchange.

For me, using SDK is better to implement serverless rather than API Gateway. Why I prefer to implementing SDK instead of API on my serverless infra?

- API Gateway is Costly
- Network hop-less
- In fact, SDK is commonly contain an API to communicate with other applications Class base and simple call such as dynamodb.put(params).promise(), lambda.invoke(params).promise(), s3.putObject(params).promise(), etc. We can see a sample API call like fetch(URL).promise(), the term is not really different
- API is more complex and some case can't or shouldn't be handled with
- SDK is not scalable? No, I dont think so. Because it's class base, it's so scalable.
- Slimming the infra and code writing, i.e to work with s3 no need deploy API+Lambda
- Speed up the process, i.e storing data to dynamodb no need business logic through API+lambda
- Easy maintaining, we only maintain our client code
- Role Policy is more scalable; etc

Comment: I have my app flow as such - users can signup to userpool & then from client side , using aws-sdk directly they should be able to put Items to dynamodb. But I dont want to store AWS IAM user access key in client side. I have heard that we can federated identity pool with user pool & identity pool can give temporary IAM credentials to client to access dynamodb & other AWS resources directly. How I can get this temporary credentials , can u include some 4-5 line code showing signIn, getting temporary access keys & calling dynamodb put operation using these temporary credentials

Comment: I started my AWS journey from this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/js-sdk-dv-v2.pdf 
You can start from the page #10 to have basic concept of generate temp credentials with cognito federated identity. For more advanced, you should exchange the Oauth2 token with and other techniques

Comment: I understood the concept of userpool vs identity pool & successfully used in my demo project. One question though, if I am directly using aws-sdk client side & doing CRUDL operations on DynamoDB table, though it is protected by IAM (& only valid AWS credentials needed for operation), if someone strips the app he will be able to see the table name or field names or userpool name , s3 bucket name, etc. Is this ok ?

Comment: that's not okay absolutely, but I care those issues by some techniques such as restricted IAM Policy condition, I never exposed my user pool ID & identity pool ID on the client, I run my oauth2 request & token exchange on lambda through http api, isolated variables, etc.. check this out some demo here https://demo.appycloud.tech/

Comment: Even AWS amplify framework uses userpool id & identity pool id on client side. They have a file called aws-exports.js which has all the values - table name, bucket name, etc

Comment: One another question though - how to handle API throttling if we are using direct sdk requests? Any suggestion? People whomever I mention seems to love this idea with few doubts , one of them is throttling

Comment: I talked with some AWS guys about and let them gave some generic pen-test to my 2 dummies. the first dummy was similar to what AWS Amplify approaches, the second one with some improvisation most specific about encapsulation & isolated variables. it's very clear, the second one was harder to be raped than the first approach :D. But I won't say no secure hole with. any system must have holes